# How to access an actor-isolated property

Tags: swift, swift5, xcode13, swift-concurrency

I try to check the actor's behavior. This is a new feature provided by Swift5.5.

I've created a playground with an example code from the official documentation [swift.org](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html):

```swift
    import Foundation
    
    actor TemperatureLogger {
        let label: String
        var measurements: [Int]
        private(set) var max: Int

        init(label: String, measurement: Int) {
            self.label = label
            self.measurements = [measurement]
            self.max = measurement
        }
    }

    let logger = TemperatureLogger(label: "Outdoors", measurement: 25)
    print(await logger.max)
    // Prints "25"
```

But my compiler fails on this example:

[image: errors]

> Swift Compiler Error:
>
> 'await' in a function that does not support concurrency
>
> Actor-isolated property 'max' can only be referenced from inside the actor

So how to access an actor-isolated property?

Maybe it's a bug in the compiler or in the example code?

Xcode Version 13.0 beta (13A5154h)
Swift Version 5.5

Comment: Try `async { print(await logger.max) }`. The "Actor-isolated property 'max' can only be referenced from inside the actor" message does seem quite unhelpful...

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks, but still fails

```error: Actors.playground:17:1: error: cannot find 'async' in scope
async {
^~~~~
```

Comment: I think async is deprecated for Task

Answer (score 23):

Put the access in an `Task` block.
Actor isolated properties synchronise and enforce exclusive access through the "cooperative thread pool" and could suspend, so this needs to run asynchronously.

```swift
let logger = TemperatureLogger(label: "Outdoors", measurement: 25)
Task {
    print(await logger.max)
    // Prints "25"
}
```

Comment: This just gives me `'async(priority:operation:)' is deprecated: \`async\` was replaced by \`Task.init\` and will be removed shortly.`

Comment: @KyLeggiero See updated answer. Creation of an async task was changed from `async` to `Task` in the most recent Swift 5.5 beta, as the error message you have got clearly shows. Perhaps an edit to the answer would have been more helpful than a downvote :)

Comment: Except this doesnt work if you need the result in the current context...

Comment: @Era Do you mean from a synchronous context? If so then yes, you'll need to make sure your 'context' is also asynchronous or use a callback or similar to return the results. It would be a violation of the asynchronous runtime model to block synchronously and wait for a result, for example.